# is it possible to construct a continuous bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

is it possible to construct a continuous bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. if it is, please give an example.If not, how to prove?

Comment: the inverse would not be continuous of course, else it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you want the map to be simply 1-1? Or do you want it also to be onto?

Comment: sorry, I meant it to be bijective, but the Peano curve is not.

Comment: @Beni: A space-filling curve is never injective.

Comment: @Alex: you might also want to change your title.

Comment: All right! I have, thanks. Julien

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You are right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *no*.

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ is a continuous bijection. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $I_n=[-n,n]$, and let $K_n=f[I_n]$. Then $\Bbb R^2=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}K_n$, so by the Baire category theorem some $K_m$ has non-empty interior. Choose $x$ and $r$ so that $B(x,r)\subseteq K_m$, and let $g=f\upharpoonright I_m$. Then $g$ is a continuous bijection from the compact set $I_m$ onto $K_m$, so $g$ is a homeomorphism. (In case this isn’t familiar, note that $g$ is closed: every closed subset of $I_m$ is compact, $g$ preserves compactness, and every compact subset of $K_m$ is closed, since $K_m$ is compact. Finally, a closed, continuous bijection is clearly a homeomorphism.)

Let $J=g^{-1}[B(x,r)]$; $B(x,r)$ is connected and open, so $J$ is an open interval in $I_m$ homeomorphic to $B(x,r)$. But this is impossible: $J$, being an interval, has cut points, and $B(x,r)$ has none.

Answer (score 7):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous and injective, then $f$ cannot be surjective. The reason is as follows. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, since $[-n,n]$ is compact, it is homeomorphic to $f([-n,n])$. Then due to [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), $f([-n,n])$ is a nowhere dense closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, by [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), $f(\mathbb{R})=\cup_{n=1}^\infty f([-n,n])$ is also nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Remark**: With an almost identical argument, the result can be generalized as follows. If $m\ne n$, then there is no continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Please refer to [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism).

Comment: Ah, that seems a result worth mentioning along with the details you give from the other steps. In particular, I certainly would not have figured out the Hausdorff condition.

Comment: @richard I dont understand how do you uses the invariance of domain theorem that you mentioned.

Comment: @EduardoSiva: Please see the "Consequences" paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), which implies that $f([-n,n])$ has no interior point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Invariance of domain isn’t actually necessary.

Comment: @richard a interval $I\in R$ do not be homeomorphic to a ball $B\in \mathbb{R}$ because if you take a point of each, we $B-{p}$ have conected and $I-{q}$ is not conected

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Do you mean it could be replaced by the argument in the second paragragh of your answer? Nevertheless, with invariance of domain, the result can be easily generalized to any dimension.

Comment: @HarryPotter: Your statement is just a special case of invariance of domain, so what is your point?

Comment: @richard  my point is that you could argue more simply, as has been shown, in my view you used a bazooka to kill an ant.

Comment: Yes, and that handles $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ for all $n\ge 2$. There is also an elementary argument that handles $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^n$ for $n>2$, though it requires a little more machinery. I prefer elementary tools when they suffice.